Why does emptyArray.every() return true in Javascript?
Why emptyArray.every() returns true? It doesn´t make sense to me because there is no element which you can apply the callBackFunction on?
Example:
let x=[];
x.every(n=>n>10);

I would expect an error...

It's true until one of the elements doesn't t meet the condition.

From the docs: "true unless callbackFn returns a falsy value for an array element, in which case false is immediately returned" and "every acts like the "for all" quantifier in mathematics. In particular, for an empty array, it returns true. (It is vacuously true that all elements of the empty set satisfy any given condition.)"

Thank you devlin carnate for your answer. It gave me some starting points for a deeper understanding!
